# Running two Tensorflow trainings in parallel using joblib and dask

Tags: python, tensorflow, dask, dask-distributed, joblib

I have the following code that runs two TensorFlow trainings in parallel using Dask workers implemented in Docker containers.

I need to launch two processes, using the same dask client, where each will train their respective models with N workers.

To that end, I do the following:

- I use `joblib.delayed` to spawn the two processes.
- Within each process I run `with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):` to execute the fit/training logic. Each training process triggers N dask workers.

The problem is that I don't know if the entire process is thread safe, are  there any concurrency elements that I'm missing?

```
# First, submit the function twice using joblib delay
delayed_funcs = [joblib.delayed(train)(sub_task) for sub_task in [123, 456]]
parallel_pool = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=2)
parallel_pool(delayed_funcs)

# Second, submit each training process
def train(sub_task):

    global client
    if client is None:
        print('connecting')
        client = Client()

    data = some_data_to_train

    # Third, process the training itself with N workers
    with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
        X = data[columns] 
        y = data[label]

        niceties = dict(verbose=False)
        model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_layers,
                loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), **niceties)
        model.fit(X, y, epochs=500, verbose = 0)
```

Comment: Your question is rather open-ended. Do you have something more specific you have a problem with? Also, you mention launching processes, and then ask about thread-safety: is your dask worker or anything else using multiple threads?

Comment: I'm just trying to check if there are any race conditions in the code I posted. As @Sultan mentioned there may be a race condition when the client is created. I tried to create the client just once outside of the `train` function and pass it as a parameter, but I get an error saying that `joblib.parallel_backend('dask')` doesn't have a client defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question, as given, could easily be marked as "unclear" for SO. A couple of notes:

- `global client` : makes the client object available outside of the fucntion. But the function is run from another process, you do not affect the other process when making the client
- `if client is None` : this is a name error, your code doesn't actually run as written
- `client = Client()` : you make a new cluster in each subprocess, each assuming the total resources available, oversubscribing those resources.
- dask knows whether any client has been created in the current process, but that doesn't help you here

You must ask yourself: why are you creating processes for the two fits at all? Why not just let Dask figure out its parallelism, which is what it's meant for.

--

-EDIT-

to answer the form of the question asked in a comment.

> My question is whether using the same client variable in these two parallel processes creates a problem.

No, the two `client` variables are unrelated to one-another. You may see a warning message about not being able to bind to a default port, which you can safely ignore. However, please don't make it `global` as this is unnecessary and makes what you are doing less clear.

--

I think I must answer the question as phrased in your comment, which I advise to add to the main question

> I need to launch two processes, using the same dask client, where each will train their respective models with N workers.

You have the following options:

- create a client with a specific known address within your program or beforehand, then connect to it
- create a default client `Client()` and get its address (e.g., `client._scheduler_identity['address']`) and connect to that
- write a scheduler information file with `client.write_scheduler_file` and use that

You will connect in the function with

```
client = Client(address)
```

or

```
client = Client(scheduler_file=the_file_you_wrote)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you saying that I shouldn't use joblib to create the two processes?

Comment: It would be fair to say, that I don't know what having two processes achieves. However, that's how the question was given, so that's how I have tried to answer,

Comment: The intent of having two processes is to run two trainings in parallel. That's why I do `joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=2)` to trigger these two processes. Inside each process, I use `joblib.parallel_backend('dask')` to train one model. My question is whether using the same client variable in these two parallel processes creates a problem.

Comment: Added a paragraph to answer this specific thing

Answer (score 2):

This is pure speculation, but one potential concurrency issue is due to `if client is None:` part, where two processes could race to create a `Client`.

If this is resolved (e.g. by explicitly creating a client in advance), then `dask` scheduler will rely on time of submission to prioritize task (unless `priority` is clearly assigned) and also the graph (DAG) structure, there are further details available in [docs](http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/scheduling-policies.html).

Comment: I moved the client creation logic outside the train method, and I get `ValueError: To use Joblib with Dask first create a Dask Client`, how to create the client in advance?

Comment: Hmm, according to the [example in the docs](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/parallel/distributed_backend_simple.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-parallel-distributed-backend-simple-py) `with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):` should be outside the call to `joblib.Parallel`...

Comment: Sultan, your example works for a single process, I need to launch two processes, using the same dask client, where each will train their respective models with N workers.